# logic to verify if the element is present in array from list of object

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an 2 array with some String values. I wanted to check if one array's all value are part of another arrays. Is there any defined method available to check it or how to implement in optimised way.

Ex:

```
arr1 = ['abc', 'def']

arr2 = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']
```

if values of array 1 is present in array 2 then only control should move ahead in code else it should return.

Comment: `(arr1 - arr2).empty?`

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you mean to _test whether one of the values in arr1 is contained in arr2_, or whether _all the values are_?

Comment: _"all value are part of another arrays"_ – do you have to take duplicates into account? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few ways of doing that. Perhaps the easiest way is to use the [Set](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) class:

```
a = ["1","2","5"]
b = ["2", "5"]

s1 = Set.new(a)
s2 = Set.new(b)

s2.subset?(s1) # => true
s1.subset?(s2) # => false                   

c = ["5", "2"]
s3 = Set.new(c)
s3.subset?(s1) # true
```

If you decide to use the [intesection (&)](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Array.html#method-i-26) method, you need to be aware that the order matters:

```
a = ["1","2","5"]
b = ["2", "5"]
c = ["5", "2"]

a & b # => ["2", "5"]
a & c # => ["2", "5"]

b & a # => ["2", "5"]
c & a # => ["5", "2"]
```

Then, you can take advantage of ==:

```
(a & b) == b # => true
(a & c) == c # => false
(b & a) == b # => true
(c & a) == c # => true
```

You can also use [all?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Array.html#method-i-all-3F):

```
a = ["1","2","5"]
b = ["2", "5"]

a.all? {|e| b.include?(e) } # => false
b.all? {|e| a.include?(e) } # => true
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(arr1 & arr2).size == arr2.size
```

or

```
 (arr1 & arr2) == arr2
```